# jquery dropdown with separate container

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/dropdown1">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/dropdown1">item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/dropdown1">item3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="submenu">
    <div class="dropdown1">content1</div>
    <div class="dropdown2">content2</div>
    <div class="dropdown3">content3</div>
</div>
```

Submenu content is invisible, css:

```
.submenu div{display:none;}
```

With jquery I want to when hover on item (*.menu ul li a*)
1. take attribute *href* without '/' and show same name *div* from .submenu.
2. add class 'active' to item (*.menu ul li a*)

And hide this *div* if mouse out from this container or menu item and remove class 'active' (like classic dropdown menu)

This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jzj5wub6/

Comment: So what you tried so far expect html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also make it this way

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/gnbL88w0/4/)

```
$('.menu a').hover(function () {
    var a = $(this).attr('href').slice(1) // taking the href value and removing /
    $('.submenu div').removeClass('active');
    $('.submenu .' + a).addClass('active')
})

$('.menu a').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $('.submenu div' ).removeClass('active');
})
```

**Edit**

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/gnbL88w0/7/)

```
$('.menu a').hover(function () {
    var a = $(this).attr('href').slice(1)
    $('.submenu div').removeClass('active');
    $('.submenu .' + a).addClass('active')
})

$('.submenu div').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('.submenu div').removeClass('active');
})
```

Comment: thanks, but i need to submenu div will not dissapear when mouse over on it

Comment: and hide() div when mouse out from 'submenu' or 'menu' item.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are a solution http://jsfiddle.net/jzj5wub6/4/

```
$('.menu a').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var link = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.submenu').find('.' + link).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var link = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('.submenu div').hide();
    },
    click: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('.submenu div').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var link = $(this).attr('class');
        $('.menu a[href="/'+link+'"]').addClass('active');
        $(this).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {        
        $('.menu a').removeClass('active');
        $('.submenu div').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: it works like tooltip, and I need like menu - container div must be visible while mouse on it

Comment: I've made an update to my answer. Check the updated answer :
)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.menu a').click(function(){
        e.preventDefault();
    })
    $('.menu li').hover(function () {
        var $target = $('.'+$(this).find('a').attr('href').substring(1), '.submenu');
        clearTimeout($target.data('hoverTimer'));
        $target.stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
    }, function () {
        var $target = $('.'+$(this).find('a').attr('href').substring(1), '.submenu');
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $target.stop(true, true).slideUp();
        }, 200);
        $target.data('hoverTimer', timer);
    });

    $('.submenu > div').hover(function () {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimer'));
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });
});
```

```css
.menu ul {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    list-style:none;
}
.menu li {
    float:left
}
.menu a {
    background:gray;
    padding:5px;
    margin-right:1px
}
.submenu div {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/dropdown1">item1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/dropdown2">item2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/dropdown3">item3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="submenu">
    <div class="dropdown1">content1</div>
    <div class="dropdown2">content2</div>
    <div class="dropdown3">content3</div>
</div>
```