# menu with separate div sections

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried for months to find away of connecting my menu, but frustratingly I've had no luck. I don't know what else I can try so I want to ask you guys if you can help.  I searched around here on Stack for an idea, this someway to describe the function I want but I'd like to utilise the data-attribute way instead of href and I want to use the on  click function instead of the hover, as it's for desktop and mobile. I also want to close the submenu with the menu a on desktop version, would toggle be an option?
link: [jquery dropdown with separate container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212967/jquery-dropdown-with-separate-container)

html

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-section="one">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-section="two">item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-section="three">item3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="submenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="one">content1</li>
        <li class="two">content2</li>
        <li class="three">content3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

content from submenu ul li is set to height:0 that I want to set to auto when triggered, or maybe add a class to the submenu ul li:

```
.submenu ul li{
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0;
.submenu ul li.active{
    height:auto;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrrossanderson/78mpwLq4/)

Comment: You want the submenu to be opened when someone clicks the parent item in the main menu?

Comment: Do you want to hide the submenu from showing, or do you want to animate the closing event? Your question uses a couple different terms: close, toggle, and I'm not entirely sure what the behavior is that you seek.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier if you nested your submenu items in with the menu headers? Seems more semantic that way as well.

Comment: Hello, Yes I want the submenu ul li  to open(height:auto) when the .menu > a is clicked. What I meant by toggle was that I'd like to use the .menu > a to close the menu should the user want to close the menu back it's original state (height:0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but try replacing

```
$(this).attr('data-section').slice(1)
```

with this

```
$(this).attr('data-section')
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78mpwLq4/3/) (based in yours)

Comment: haha, that does work doesn't it. brilliant. Now all I have to do is use the same .menu li a to close the menu down again if the user wants to do this. Any ideas @MuZk ?

Comment: You could ask if your li target has already the class. If it does, then just remove the class. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/78mpwLq4/5/

Comment: I'm so grateful to you for helping me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the .slice(1). I don't know why you add this one.

when you click on the menu link, jquery will remove active class from list and it will added to a new link related to menu link by data-section.